# программа, к которой подключаются 2 dll файла

Tags: c++, dll

из dll_1 вызывается первая функция, эта функция вызывает вторую функцию из dll_2, вторая функция вызывает третью из dll_1, третья функция вызывает четвёртую функцию из dll_2, четвёртая функция выводит надпись. как это сделать? вот мои попытки написать код.

dll_1:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void first_func(void)
{
    cout << "First function in first dll\n";
    three_func();
}
void second_func(void)
{
    cout << "second function in first dll.\n";
    four_func();
}

_declspec(dllexport) void three_func(void)
{
    three_func();
}

_declspec(dllexport) void four_func(void)
{
    four_func();
}
```

dll_2:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void three_func(void)
{
    cout << "three function in second dll\n";
    second_func();
}
void four_func(void)
{
    cout << "four function in second dll\nНу нифига себе.";
}
_declspec(dllexport) void second_func(void)
{
    second_func();
}
```

Comment: Так и сделать, как описываете

Comment: Эээ... А для чего странная конструкция `_declspec(dllexport) void three_func(void) { three_func(); }`? Почему нельзя без неё, а declspec навесить на исходную функцию? Плюс нужен header, понятно.

Comment: можно легче? в хедере я написал 
void first_func(void);
void second_func(void);
void three_func(void);
void four_func(void);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал вот как.

В первой DLL в эспортируемом header'е (Dll1.h):

```
#ifdef DLL1_EXPORTS
#define DLL1_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL1_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

DLL1_API void first_func(void);
DLL1_API void second_func(void);
```

В cpp-файле:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Dll1.h"
#include "Dll2.h"

DLL1_API void first_func(void)
{
    cout << "First function in first dll\n";
    three_func();
}

DLL1_API void second_func(void)
{
    cout << "second function in first dll.\n";
    four_func();
}
```

В свойствах проекта в Preprocessor definitions добавил `DLL1_EXPORTS` (обязательно!).

Аналогично же сделал бы и с Dll2. Всё!

---

Возможно, имеет смысл для экспортируемых функций ещё добавить `extern "C"` (разумеется, в том же макросе).